# Could you please find the mistake in this (false) argument?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x) : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined as:
$$f(x) = x^2+1$$
We can see that:
$$f(5) = f(3) + 16$$ Differentiating w.r.t $x$, we get:
$$f'(5) = f'(3)$$
which is absurd since $f'(5) = 10$ and $f'(3) = 6$. Therefore, I have certainly made a mistake. I can think of a few probable reasons why this is wrong, out of which one or more may be the answer:

1. I've not differentiated w.r.t $x$, since the constants were already plugged in, so I've differentiated by a constant (which is wrong).
2. You can't differentiate like this. First, we differentiate to find $f'(x)$ then find $f'(a)$ for $x = a$ and the relations accordingly, which I normally follow, except for this question.
3. Technically, $f(5), f(3), 16$ are constants, so differentiating w.r.t $x$ would yield $0$ on both sides.

I would like to know the mistake in the steps in an *intuitive way*.

Comment: I am not sure how we can explain $10\neq 6$ in a "more intuitive way". Indeed, differentiating $26=f(5)=f(3)+16=10+16$ makes no sense. As constant functions it gives $0=0$.

Comment: It is wrong for the reasons 2 and 3 but I don't see exaclty what you need more (what would be an intuitive way). I excluded reason 1 only because I don't understand what you mean by "diferentiated by a constant".

Comment: I'm asking if the original equation was true, then how did the equation received after differentiating was incorrect?

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I can elaborate. You have to explain in what sense you are "differentiating" the equation $26=10+16$, i.e., $f(5)=f(3)+16$, see the first comment. In any case, the conclusion $10=6$, i.e., $f'(5)=f'(3)$ is false.

Comment: oh! does this mean the reason 3?

Comment: Reason (3) tells you that you should expect $0=0$, but doesn't explain why you didn't get it. (BTW, writing "Technically" seems to suggest that there's some tricky nuance involved when actually it's quite straightforward: "*Because* $f(3)$, $f(5)$, and $16$ are constants, ...".) The *error* is that you didn't apply the Chain Rule.
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(5)) = \frac{d}{dx}( f(3)+16 ) \quad\to\quad f'(5)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}5 = f'(3)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}3 + \frac{d}{dx}16 \quad\to\quad 0=0+0$$

Comment: @Blue thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Could you please find the mistake in this (false) argument?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The issues will be clear if you write out the definitions; the derivative of a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ is defined as:
\begin{align*}
f'(x_0) = \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
\end{align*}
when the limit exists. In short 'differentiating both sides' can only be done if what you are 'operating' on are functions, and they have to be differentiable to do so.

Comment: does this mean that the reason 2 is the mistake?

Comment: It is point 3 essentially; 'finding' $f'(x)$ for all $x$ is not something that makes sense unless you already know that the limit exists for the entire domain; if that is the case you define a new function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $g(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x)-f(x_0)/x-x_0, x_0 \in [a,b]$. We just call $g$ the same as the function $f'$

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you mean by an "intuitive way" but differentiation is about getting information on a function by looking at how it is evolving (namely by looking at its tangent lines). Although differentiation gives you a point-to-point output (the derivative function), it comes from looking at the function **around** fixed points. There needs to be some kind of movement.
So it doesn't make sense to differentiate something that do not evolves (that do not have a dependance in some variable, something that's not a function), here your constant relation $f(5) = f(3) + 16$.
Constant functions and constant relations are not the same thing.

Comment: Nice intuitive explanation!